# Amazon blocked port 80 and 443 on my instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Amazon AWS sent me an email about warning that my instance have been behaving like **Phising** that is against AWS Customer Agreement.

And they noticed that they blocked port 80 and 443 which are for HTTP and HTTPS respectively.

Google Safe Browsing also reported that some code injection was made to one of my websites. After a cleaning, Google stopped blocking my website displaying in the search result.

So, how can I unblock my ports?

Comment: Have you checked your security groups?

Answer (score 1):

Contact [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/support) and tell them that you've resolved the issue and ask them what you need to do to get unblocked. Make sure you reference the original incident e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Elastic IP service which EC2 provides, then then is high chance that the random elastic IP which you got might be used before for phishing. I would suggest you to disassociate the Elastic IP with that box and associate a new EIP. And make all the associated Route 53 changes also.

To confirm that its not your box which is doing the actual phising, you can check the logs of the services running on port 443 and 80

Or you can run tcpdump to check all the outbound connections from your box.

To unblock the ports, use support services provided by AWS:

https://aws.amazon.com/support/